# jQuery UI autocomplete copy input value to another input

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to copy input value from JQUI Autocomplete to another input, that also has autocomplete function enabled.

Here's what i have in HTML

```
<label for="LocationFrom">Location</label> <input id="LocationFrom" />
<label for="LocationTo">Location</label> <input id="LocationTo" />
```

and JS

```
$(function() {
$('#LocationFrom, #LocationTo').autocomplete({
    source: [
    "airport",
    "downtown",
    "street",
    "city"
            ],
    minLength: 0
})
.focus(function()
{
var self = this;

window.setTimeout(function()
{
if (self.value.length == 0)
  $(self).autocomplete('search', '');
});})});
```

I tried with this, but it doesn't work

```
$('#LocationFrom').change(function() {
$('#LocationTo').val($(this).val());
});
```

Here's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teva/AknyR/)

tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the jquery autocomplete dose not fire the 'onchange' event;
You can use autocomplete change event to solve this.

```
$(function () {
$('#LocationFrom, #LocationTo').autocomplete({
    source : [
        "airport",
        "downtown",
        "street",
        "city"
    ],
    minLength : 0,
    change : function () {
        $('#LocationTo').val($(this).val());
    }
})
.focus(function () {
    var self = this;

    window.setTimeout(function () {
        if (self.value.length == 0)
            $(self).autocomplete('search', '');
    });
})});
```

Comment: This works OK, but i wan't it to add value to new input without having to remove focus from first field. Like Gautam suggested bellow.

Comment: You can use the close event instead of change.By using close the second value will be updated whenever the autocomplete suggestions list closes  without the need to remove the focus from the first field. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please use select event.

I updated fiddle for your reference.

http://jsfiddle.net/AknyR/16/

```
$(function() {
    $('#LocationFrom, #LocationTo').autocomplete({
        source: [
        "airport",
        "downtown",
        "street",
        "city"
                ],
        minLength: 0,
        select: function( event, ui ) {

            $('#LocationTo').val(ui.item.value);
           $('#LocationFrom').val('');
            return false;
}
    })
    .focus(function()
    {
  var self = this;

  window.setTimeout(function()
  {
    if (self.value.length == 0)
      $(self).autocomplete('search', '');
  });

})

$('#LocationFrom').change(function() {
$('#LocationTo').val($(this).val());
});

});
```

Comment: This is good, but can you disabled changing input 1 if input 2 is changed manually later. Now, if i select input 1, input 2 has same value, but if i wan't change just input 2, this value is also changed in input 1.

Comment: ohh i got your  question in that case instead of defining like this  $('#LocationFrom, #LocationTo').autocomplete  define them seperatly like  $('#LocationFrom').autocomplete  and  $('#LocationTo').autocomplete hope this will help